# Weird scanf issue in C

Tags: c

Let's say that I use `scanf` to, for example, read a character from the keyboard. After that I use `printf` to print the character I just read.

```
scanf("%c",&ch);
printf("%c",ch);
```

When `scanf` is reading the character, I must press enter to continue and run the `printf`, right?

And let's say I enter `ABCD` with the keyboard. After that `printf` will print `A`.

But when I do this:

```
do {
   scanf("%c",&ch);
   printf("%c",ch);
} while (ch!='\n');
```

and enter `ABCD` with the keyboard, I assume that the `printf` must print `A`. And because `A` is not `\n` it will continue the loop, right?

But instead of this it will print `ABCD`. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you type in `"ABCD\n"`, each `scanf("%c",&ch);` reads one `char` from the input buffer, until the newline is reached.

So after the `'A'` is printed, there is still a `"BCD\n"` in the buffer, so that the next `scanf` immediately succeeds reading another `char`, `'B'` in the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: but scanf supposed to keep the first digit only

Comment: But you have a loop, and several `char`s in the input buffer, so the next `scanf` reads the next `char` from the buffer, until that is empty or a newline is found.

Comment: and if i want to keep only the first letter from input buffer and in the next loop i want to keep the first letter from another sequence ?

Comment: @user1809300 If you want to read first character of a line, you need to read the first character and then read+discard the rest of the line.

Comment: Then you need to clear the input buffer after each scan, `int c; while((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'); if (c == EOF) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`. Or something similar.

Comment: @user1809300 Do note, that you can have multiple lines in the buffer, not just one.

Comment: ok thank you...adn what do you mean multiple lines in buffer?

Comment: and another thing : when i dont have a loop and scanf ABCD why does it keep only the first digit without reaching a newline /n

Comment: @user1809300 Because you are reading one character. What the loop does it that you read one character four times (edit: five times).

Comment: Without a loop, only one `scanf("%c", &ch);` is executed, so it takes only one character from the input buffer. If you do something like `char buffer[100]; fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin); printf("%s\n", buffer);`, you will see that the other characters you typed were still in the input buffer.

Answer (score 4):

> in scanf i must press enter to continue and run the printf right?

Nope. As long as there is a character to be read, it will be read.

> i put in scanf ABCD after that printf will print A ...

If you input ABCD and enter, the input will now contain five characters. A, B, C, D and a newline. Your cycle will read the characters A, B, C, D in sequence and then read the newline.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` does not wait for you to press enter, it simple tries to read in what you typed if it matched your format string. If you had used `%s`, then it would wait until a whitespace character before matching.

This thread may also be useful: [why does scanf not wait for user input after it fails one time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805414/why-does-scanf-not-wait-for-user-input-after-it-fails-one-time)