# scanf() is not waiting for user input

Tags: c, scanf

I am working on making tree using doubly linked list in c.
I use recursive call in that function , but somehow it do not works.
my code is :

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *right;
    struct node *left;
};

struct node* getNode()
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp= (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->right=NULL;
    temp->left=NULL;
    return temp; 
}
```

here in the below function I am getting the problem.

```
struct node* maketree()
{
    struct node *t;
    t=getNode(); 
    int value;
    char choice1='n',choice2='n';
    printf("\nenter the value to the node");
    scanf("%d",&value);
    t->data=value;
    printf("\nis there any left child??\n");
    scanf("%c",&choice1);               // I think here my problem is .
    if (choice1 == 'y')
    {
        t->left=maketree();   
    }

    printf("\nis there any right child??\n");
    scanf("%c",&choice2);
    if (choice2 == 'y' || choice2 == 'Y')
    {
        t->right=maketree();   

    }
    return t;
}

int main (void)
{
    struct node *t;
    t=maketree();
    return;
}
```

the code compiles properly , but the problem is , the code do not wait for my choice (I use `scanf()` , C should wait untill I enter the input to the terminal.)
but the output is :

```
enter the value to the node4

is there any left child??

is there any right child??
```

please assist.

Comment: If you checked the `scanf()` return code for validation, you'd probably have found the problem by now.

Comment: Aaaaaand kaboom. Use `fgets()` and **stay the hell away from `scanf()`** if you don't understand how it works. It's not a function for beginners.

Comment: possible duplicate of [scanf won't ask for input the second time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372923/scanf-wont-ask-for-input-the-second-time) and of [Program doesn't wait for user input with scanf(“%c”,&yn);](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464620/program-doesnt-wait-for-user-input-with-scanfc-yn) and of [why does scanf not wait for user input after it fails one time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805414/why-does-scanf-not-wait-for-user-input-after-it-fails-one-time)

Comment: sir,but I used the same `scanf()` in seperate program to check , whether I use it properly or not , but it works correctly.

Comment: You either need to pay attention to your compiler's warnings, or you need to turn the warnings on, or you need to get a better compiler.  Your `main()` function returns `int` (that's good — so often we see `void main()`, which is wrong), but ends with `return;` where it should be `return 0;`.

Comment: I'd suggest you stop fiddling around with the problems that can occur with mixing different methods of input, and just get yourself a tried and true line input function, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : please suggest me some compiler , because my compiler did not give me a single warning while executing the above code.

Comment: @user2670535 MinGW is a good one , You have to make your compiler warn you its lazy :P try to compile with `-Wall` option . One google search would have made the life easier for you..... as for your question just use `getchar()` after `scanf()` or you better don't use it :)

Answer (score 8):

The `scanf("%d", &value)` left a newline behind; the `scanf("%c", &choice1)` reads that newline.

Check the return values from `scanf()` every time.  And print what you read to help you debug your code.  Make sure your program got what you think it got.

A simple fix is to replace the second `scanf()` with `scanf(" %c", &choice1)`.  The blank in the format string eats up white space, including newlines, and reads the first non-blank character.  Of course, it too leaves a newline behind.

As intimated in the comments, it is usually easier to control things with:

```
char line[4096];

if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) == 0)
    ...deal with EOF...
```

And then you can use `sscanf()` to parse the line.  This general technique is quite a bit less error prone than using `scanf()` directly; it is also a lot easier to report errors coherently when you have the whole line to include in the error report.  That matters more when you're reading multiple conversions per call to `scanf()`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, the `\r` is sent to the second scanf, remaining from the first scanf.

And since you're reading only one char with scanf (which is BTW not recomended - use `getchar()` instead) it accepts the carriage return (`\r`).
If you still want to use the second scanf, make a flush of the standard input: `fflush(stdin)` right after the first scanf().

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with `scanf()`, learning to use it is a good exercise in reading documentation, but it DOES work.  Learning to use it is a good sample of what programmers do!

As a first guess, try these statements in your code:

```
char &choice1[2];  // allow for %c\0, but even this can be avoided
// etc.
scanf("%1s", &choice1);
if (tolower(choic1[0]) == 'y') { // etc.
```

The `%1s` reads and discards white space, including new lines, and the 1 limits the number of chars that qualify as a string.

If this change does NOT work, let me know, and I will test/use your code to find a fix.