# why does my int while loop keeps going when i scan for a number?

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

I'm having a problem with a while loop. I have to enter a number which is bigger than 0 and below 81. when I use numbers like -1,0,1,2,82 it is going good and I get the expected result, but when I use a letter it keeps going through my while loop. I've used the debugger in eclipse and when I'm at the while loop `amount` is automatically set to '0' because of the failed scanf. Why does it keep looping when I insert a letter?

[image: eclipseDebug]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int amount = 0;
    printf("Give a number:\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d",&amount);
    while(amount <= 0 || amount >= 81){
        printf("Wrong input try again.\n");
        printf("Give a number:\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        scanf("%d",&amount);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `%d` is not for letter. You need to convert your `char` inputs to `int` before validation in `while`.

Comment: Using wrong format specifiers is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Dayalrai I get that, but at the moment it sets amount to 0. which is an integer. so it should be valid for my while. right?

Comment: If the input is a letter, and `amount` is set to zero, then of course the loop continues, because the `while` clause evaluates to true: `while (amount <= 0 ||` <-- amount is less then, or ***equal to zero***. A quick tip: research the problems that `scanf` has, and _check the return values of functions as much as possible_

Comment: Character that can not be interpreted as a number persist without being consumed.、

Comment: You must check *the return value*  of `scanf()` before you use the scanned value. It's I/O, it can fail. Not sure why so many fail at this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure the `scanf()` worked. Use the returned value to do that

```
if (scanf("%d", &amount) != 1) /* error */;
```

When it doesn't work (because eg a letter was found in input) you probably want to get rid of the cause of the error.

A better option to get input from users is to use `fgets()`

Answer (score 1):

See this related question: [scanf() is not waiting for user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18372421/scanf-is-not-waiting-for-user-input)

The reason is that when you press enter with a char, scanf failed and didn't eat up the char in the input feed. As a result, the next block begins having whatever you entered before.

You can check that by adding a `getchar()` before the `scanf()` inside the `while` loop. You'll notice that it'll repeat the while loop as many times as your line has invalid characters, then stop and wait for input. The `getchar()` ate one of the invalid chars in the input each time the loop ran.

It would be better not to use `scanf` like that, though. Take a look a this resource: 
[Reading a line using scanf() not good?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294809/reading-a-line-using-scanf-not-good)