# Forcing user to enter an Integer using a While loop in C

Tags: c, integer, do-while

I am trying to get the user to enter a integer to be later used in the program I want it to force user to enter an input until it is an integer. When I run this code it goes on an infinite loop like so:

> Enter smallest operator: Enter smallest operator: Enter smallest operator: Enter smallest operator: Enter smallest operator: Enter smallest operator:..........

I think the issue is with the scanner but I am unsure as to how I should approach it.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char operator;
    int largestOpperator, smallestOpperator;

    printf("Enter The Table Operator (+, -, *, /, %%, or R): ");
    scanf("%c",&operator);

    /*while(!(operator == '+' || operator == '-' || operator == '*' || operator == '/' ||operator == '%' || operator == 'R'))
    {

        printf("Enter Appropriate Table Operator (+, -, *, /, %%, or R): ");
        scanf(" %c",&operator); //requires space as a way to skip the enter when char is scanning!!
    }*/

    do{
        if(!isdigit(smallestOpperator))
            printf("Enter smallest operator: ");
        else{
            printf("Enter an actual number: ");
            scanf(" %d", &smallestOpperator);
        }

    }while(!isdigit(smallestOpperator));


    printf("Enter largest operator: ");
    scanf("%d", &largestOpperator);

    {
        printf("Enter a valid integer: ");
        scanf("%d", &largestOpperator);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the entire program rather than a snippet?

Comment: Don't omit `{` braces `}` from code blocks. It's a magnet for errors; better just to never do it, and then you won't make those mistakes.

Comment: What is `smallestOpperator`, show how it is declared. And also: has `smallestOpperator` been initialized before your piece of code? If not, then your code is completely wrong anyway. Please show more relevant code. Read this: [mcve]

Comment: Don't use `scanf` for user input. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144459/using-scanf-to-accept-user-input

Comment: `isdigit` works on charactes, not on integers; however, you read an integer into `smallestOpperator` so `isdigit` will generally fail. Solution: read a char into `smallestOpperator` using `%c` in `scanf`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I changed it to char type and it worked Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently `isdigit(smallestOperator)` is returning `false`, because that's the conditional on the `while`, and you're seeing an infinite loop.

The sensible way to check the value of `smallestOperator` is to run your code in a *debugger* -- this will show you the type of the variable, its value, its in-memory representation - everything you could possibly need.

A dirtier way to achieve the same thing, is to add *debugging printfs* to your code, to print the value before it's checked.

However, we can see that you're using `scanf(" %d", ...)` to read `smallestOperator`.  The manpage for `scanf` says:

> d - Matches an optionally signed decimal integer; the next pointer must be a pointer to int.

So you're getting an *integer* from `scanf` then testing to see whether it's a *character* that's a digit.

You have two options to fix this:

### Read a char, test it, convert it

Get a *char* from scanf: `scanf(" %c", &smallestOperatorAsChar)` -- then test it with `isDigit()`, then convert it to an integer: [Convert a character digit to the corresponding integer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628761/convert-a-character-digit-to-the-corresponding-integer-in-c)

### (Better) Let scanf() tell you about conversion errors

You should always check the return value from IO calls anyway. `scanf()` returns the number of items it's successfully converted. If it's fewer than the number you expected, you can use that to trigger your error handling.

```
int rc = scanf("%d", &i);
char junkChar;
while(rc < 1) {
    printf("Invalid");
    scanf("%c", &junkChar);
    rc = scanf("%d", &i);
}
```

See: [why does scanf not wait for user input after it fails one time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805414/why-does-scanf-not-wait-for-user-input-after-it-fails-one-time) -- in which the accepted answer observes that `scanf()` isn't a great stdin input mechanism, so you shouldn't work too hard trying to work around it: either take control by writing your own routines around `fgets()` or bring in a cleverer library.